# Handling external javascript in phonegap when internet access fails

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app that, so far, has all of its javascript files local.  This means that even if there is no internet access, the app will work (minus ajax calls)

Right now the code is set up to handle failed ajax calls and wait for internet access to return.  I want to add a plug-in, however, that requires:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

My concern is this: What if someone launches my app when there is no internet access?  This call will fail, yet my app will still function until I try to call the code that relies on this script.

Is there a reasonable way to have script call "retry" if they fail to reload?